# Pass fields from factory to another class

Tags: jakarta-ee, vaadin

There is a fields factory -

```
    ...
public IncomingFieldFactory(MainView app) {
        hbnContainer = new HbnContainer<Incoming>(Incoming.class, app);
    }
    @Override
    public Field createField(Container container, Object itemId,
            Object propertyId, Component uiContext) {

        final Field f = super.createField(container, itemId, propertyId, uiContext);
        if(f != null) {
            if(f instanceof TextField) {
                TextField tf = (TextField) f;
                tf.setWidth("100%");
            }

            if(propertyId.equals("incomingDate")) {
                ((DateField) f).setResolution(DateField.RESOLUTION_MIN);
                f.setWidth("100%");
            }

            if(propertyId.equals("incomingBalance")) {
                f.setEnabled(false);
            }

            if(propertyId.equals("incomingValue")) {
                incomingValueT = f;
               ...
...

    public Field getIncomingValueT() {
        return incomingValueT;
    }
...
```

I want to pass some fields to another class to manage them (enable / disable), but get `NullPointerException` when calling -

```
...
Field f = incomingFieldFactory.getIncomingValueT();
f.setEnabled(false);
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field is created only when `Form.setItemDataSource()` or `Form.addItemProperty()` is called, so you need to make sure that you call `getIncomingValueT()` *after* `setItemDataSource()`.

Also note that the item data source must contain a property named "incomingValue" for the field to be created at all.